# Jquery: How to Change attributes back, when the checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change already set colors in css back when the checkbox is not checked.
(When checkbox is not checked, it doesn't change colors back)

HTML:

```
<div class="dark-mode">
   <label class="switch" for="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
       <div class="slider round"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
height: 100%;
color: #e5e5e5;
background: #181818;
transition: ease-out 250ms;
```

}

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#checkbox[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
           if($(this).prop('checked')){
              $('body').css({
                  'background': '#F9F9F9',
                  'color' : '#333333'
                });
              $('footer').css({
                  'background': '#E5E5E5'
              });
           }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zbpLcky/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the properties back to an empty string to revert to the default CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#checkbox[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
          $('body').css({
              'background': $(this).prop('checked') ? '#F9F9F9' : '',
              'color' : $(this).prop('checked') ? '#333333' : ''
            });
          $('footer').css({
              'background': $(this).prop('checked') ? '#E5E5E5' : ''
          });
           
    });
});
```

```css
body{
height: 100%;
color: #e5e5e5;
background: #181818;
transition: ease-out 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dark-mode">
   <label class="switch" for="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
       <div class="slider round"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

Or you could do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('dark');
    });
});
```

```css
body{
height: 100%;
color: #e5e5e5;
background: #181818;
transition: ease-out 250ms;
}

body.dark {
background: #F9F9F9;
color: #333333;
}

body.dark footer {
background: #E5E5E5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dark-mode">
   <label class="switch" for="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
       <div class="slider round"></div>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is a short part of my whole site, i have to change a lot of element's attributes, and isn't there any shorter way to change it back?
I'm trying to make code more complicated and short

Comment: Then why not add it to the css and just toggle a class?  See second snippet